# Reversing string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got an sql question. I have a table containing a column named title that store a string like this in all raws.

```
"Prenom - Nom (85)".
```

I would like to know if there is a way in sql to change that string like this :

```
"Nom - Prenom"
```

It means, I would like to reverse it and then delete the " (85).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to delete the last four charachters? and also "-" would always be there?

Comment: delete it and then reverse the first string si as i get nom - prenom

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
select concat(substring_index(left(col, length(col) - instr(reverse(col), ' ')), ' - ', -1),
              ' - ',
              substring_index(col, ' - ', 1)
             )
```

This assume that you want something a bit more general than getting rid of the `'(85)'`; it removes the final word.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly as hell and almost certainly won't work for all of your cases. But this works for the example you have posted:

```
select concat(
substring_index(substring_index("Prenom - Nom (85)"," (",1)," - ",-1),
" - ",
substring_index(substring_index("Prenom - Nom (85)"," (",1)," - ",1)
);
```

Comment: Am goint to test this and give feedback.